# Serilog Indefinite Loop logging base classes

Tags: c#, serilog

How do I avoid creating a loop with Serilog Sinks that I want to log.
The problem is that the base classes "MyTcpServer" and "MyTcpClient" use Serilog.
But since TcpSink also uses the same classes, sending a log entry will indefinitely loop.

How do I prevent this?

```
Main()
{
  Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.TcpSink() //this a TcpListener/Server listening on port 1234
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

  MyTcpServer AnotherServer = new MyTcpServer(4321);
}

public class MyTcpServer
{
   ///this class contains Log.Verbose|Debug|Error
   private List<MyTcpClient> clients;
}

public class MyTcpClient
{
   ///this class contains Log.Verbose|Debug|Error
}

public class TcpServerSink : ILogEventSink
{
  MyTcpServer server;
  public TcpServerSink(int port = 1234)
  {
     server = new MyTcpServer(1234);
  }
  public void Emit(LogEvent logevent)
  {
    string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Serialize(logevent);
    server.Send(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have cyclic dependency here... TcpServerSink is used by Serilog and Serilog is used by TcpServerSink. I think you should logs of TcpServerSink pushed to a different location.. event logs or a separate sink in Serilog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two options here

- Use `MyTcpServer` in `TcpServerSink` but don't log to `TcpServerSink`
- Don't use `MyTcpServer` in `TcpServerSink`

For the first solution make `MyTcpServer` dependent on `ILogger` rather than using static `Log` dependency. This way you can pass whatever logger you want or just disable logging in your sink:

```
server = new MyTcpServer(SilentLogger.Instance, 1234);
```

I personally prefer the second solution. Because you should log to Serilog sinks only events related to your application logic. `TcpServerSink` is not related to application logic. A common approach used in other Serilog sinks is the usage of static `SelfLog` that writes to some`TextWriter`. E.g.

```
SelfLog.Out = Console.Error;
```

And then you can use this self-log to write some info about your sink. Also instead of `MyTcpServer` your sink should use something like plain `TcpClient`. You can check a [Splunk TcpSink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-splunk/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.TCP/Sinks/Splunk/TcpSink.cs) example.

Answer (score 1):

One option worth considering is to use `Log.ForContext<MyTcpServer>()` when logging within the TCP server:

```cs
Log.ForContext<MyTcpServer>().Information("Hello!");
```

and filter these messages out for the TCP sink:

```cs
    // dotnet add package Serilog.Expressions
    .WriteTo.Conditional(
        "SourceContext not like 'MyNamespace.MyTcpServer%'",
        wt => wt.TcpSink())
    .WriteTo.Console()
```

This has the advantage of getting errors from the TCP sink through to the console, but the drawback that if you forget to use a contextual logger inside the TCP server you'll still stack overflow.